# loop through json object and check if URL ends in certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
for(var j=0; j<product.image_groups[0].images.length; j++){
                          console.log("images in json" + product.image_groups[0].images[j].link)

                    }
```

This `product.image_groups[0].images[j].link`  returns a a URL for example:

```
http://images.domain.com/is/image/domain/hbeu50274296_021_11
http://images.domain.com/is/image/domain/hbeu50274296_021_10
http://images.domain.com/is/image/domain/hbeu50274296_021_21
```

Within the loop I want to save  only the URL that ends in `_21` into a variable not sure how I would do this. I guess with a regex but how exactly?

Comment: Yes, you can use a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string.match` function. The below match function will match the string only if it end's with a `_21` substring. `$` asserts that we are at the end of a line.

```
for(var j=0; j<product.image_groups[0].images.length; j++){
    if (product.image_groups[0].images[j].link.match(/_21$/)) {
                          console.log("images in json" + product.image_groups[0].images[j].link)

                    }
}
```

OR

Use `regex.test` function.

```
for(var j=0; j<product.image_groups[0].images.length; j++){
    if (/_21$/.test(product.image_groups[0].images[j].link)) {
                          console.log("images in json" + product.image_groups[0].images[j].link)

                    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
var l = ["http://images.domain.com/is/image/domain/hbeu50274296_021_11","http://images.domain.com/is/image/domain/hbeu50274296_021_10","http://images.domain.com/is/image/domain/hbeu50274296_021_21"];
for (i=0;i<l.length;i++) {
  if(l[i].match(/_21$/)) {
    console.log(l[i])
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
http://images.domain.com/is/image/domain/hbeu50274296_021_21
```

Comment: I think you shoud use `/_21$/.test(string)` instead of `string.match(/_21$/)`. Its faster and test returns a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the url by `_` and check the last value to see if it's `21`. Something like this:

```
for (var j = 0; j < product.image_groups[0].images.length; j++) {
    var finalPart = product.image_groups[0].images[j].link.split('_').pop();
    if (finalPart == '21') {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: you are assigning `'21'` to `finalPart`, there are one or two `=` missing in the `if`

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the list of images into new list, on given requirement. The easiest way to check, as for me - simply using `indexOf` method.

```
var images = product.image_groups[0].images;
var results = images.reduce(function (list, url) {
  if (url.indexOf('_21') === url.length - 3) {
    list.push(url);
  }

  return list;
}, []);

// use results here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that, clean, simple and fast.

```
var allImages = product.image_groups[0].images;

for ( //make a for to get all images
    var j
    in allImages
) {
    if (allImages[j].link.slice(-2) == "21") { //check if last 2 characters are "21";
        console.log("images in json" + allImages[j].link);
    }
}
```